# Can somebody give me detailed construction how to find table scans with Sql Profiler?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SqlServer 2008. A usefull link is also ok. I've found some links, but since I'm not an expert with Sql Profiler, I can't seem to find how I would do this.

By the way, some data is retrieved with Stored Procedures, but others are done with sql in the .NET server layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Management Studio, go to the Query portion of the menu and go down to "Include Actual Execution Plan", this will create a new tab when you execute a new query.

Edit for SQL Server 2008

If your doing SQL Profiler, turn on the trace Scans:Scan Started and Scans:Scan Ended

Comment: Sorry, I had wrong version of SQL Server up, just swapped to 2008 and found it.